# how to create or extract a silent mp3 from a video file using ffmpeg or mencoder?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, mencoder

I am looking to create an mp3 of silence that is the same duration as the input video file using either **ffmpeg** or **mencoder**.

Using ffmpeg I have tried this:

```
ffmpeg -y -i in.avi -ab 8k -ac 1 -vol 0 -acodec libmp3lame out.mp3
```

Which works great if the video has an audio track but fails miserably if it does not.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you *have* to use ffmpeg for this? It stands to reason that any attempt to extract audio that isn't actually there would fail. It would be a relatively straightforward task to 1) create a blank WAV file of the same length as the video, then 2) convert the blank WAV to an MP3 with any number of tools.

Comment: You can add silent audio to a video with `ffmpeg -shortest -ar 44100 -acodec pcm_s16le -f s16le -ac 2 -i /dev/zero -i in.avi -vcodec copy -acodec libmp3lame out.avi -map 1:0 -map 0:0`

Comment: No, I don't have a strict requirement for ffmpeg; my requirement is to create the silent mp3 that is the same length as the video and to be able to use a command line tool for this.  I suppose I should have asked a slightly different question to reflect that.